# Does arqade support questions about modifications for games?

Tags: support

So yesterday I asked a question about a plugin for a minecraft server.
I got 1 comment before I deleted this question. It read:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for a modded Minecraft server. The only tech support we provide for Minecraft is for vanilla only.

However, I think this is unfair as I have found multiple questions asking about plugins:

[What's the best way to restrict gamemode per-world in MultiWorld?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/195068/whats-the-best-way-to-restrict-gamemode-per-world-in-multiworld)

[How do I disable commands for only 1 or 2 opped players (like worldedit and vanish)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/187933/how-do-i-disable-commands-for-only-1-or-2-opped-players-like-worldedit-and-vani/188338#188338)

my question is, does Arqade really support questions on modded servers?

My question (deleted):
 I  am new to Spigot and servers in general.
 So today I downloaded the MultiWorld plugin and make a new world name Survival (using /mw create). I joined the server, and tried to go to Survival. However, it gives an error stating their is no world named Survival loaded. So I go and load Survival (using /mw load Survival). But then, the console clears and the Java host exits. Same with the server.
 Does anyone know how to fix this, by any chance?
 IF YOU need files of the server I will gladly post them.

Comment: Here is the link to our decision on whether modded Minecraft technical issues should be supported: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Re-read the close vote of mine. It is specifically mentioning *tech support*. Also, it's *Minecraft* tech support. This is key. We decided a few months ago that we are no longer providing tech support for modded Minecraft, and the fact that you're running a modded server falls squarely in that category. More to the point, your question is asking us to diagnose and resolve why your server is crashing on you. That's tech support, through and through.

That said, we still support gameplay related questions about Minecraft mods. How they work, what they do, that sort of thing. My general rule of thumb is: we'll help you figure out how stuff in the mod works. What we *won't* do is help you get it running.